# How should I change this function to delete 1 particular entry(name and phone number),instead of the whole record(this function is currently doing)?

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
void delete_record(){
char num[15];
int found=0;
ifstream delet("phone.dat",ios::binary);
ofstream ooo("temp.dat:",ios::binary);
cout<<"Enter number to delete:";
cin>>num;
delet.seekg(0,ios::beg);
while(delet.read((char*)&rec,sizeof(rec))){
if(strcmp(num,rec.phone)==0){
found=1;
cout<<"Name:"<<rec.name<<"\t"<<"Number:"<<rec.phone<<endl;
sleep(5);
cout<<"\nNumber Deleted:";
}
if(strcmp(num,rec.phone)!=0)
ooo.write((char*)&rec,sizeof(rec));
if(found==0)
cout<<"Record not found:";
ooo.close();
delet.close();
remove("phone.dat");
rename("temp.dat","phone.dat");
getch();
}
```

}

I am trying to make a computerized telephone directory with cpp and file handling, I want to make a function to delete a particular entry(name,corresponding phone number) and not whole data in that particular file. Please help me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple mistakes there. Check my comments in code.

```
void delete_record() 
{
    char num[15];
    int found = 0;
    ifstream delet("phone.dat", ios::binary);
    ofstream ooo("temp.dat", ios::binary); // extra ':'
    cout << "Enter number to delete:";
    cin >> num;
    delet.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while (delet.read((char*)&rec, sizeof(rec)))
    {
        found = 0; // set back to 0
        if (strcmp(num, rec.phone) == 0) 
        {
            found = 1;
            cout << "Name:" << rec.name << "\t" << "Number:" << rec.phone << endl;
            sleep(5);
            cout << "\nNumber Deleted:";
        }

        if (strcmp(num, rec.phone) != 0)
            ooo.write((char*)&rec, sizeof(rec));

        if (found == 0)
            cout << "Record not found:";
    }
    // this has to be out of while scope
    ooo.close();
    delet.close();
    remove("phone.dat");
    rename("temp.dat", "phone.dat");
    getch();
}
```

And my advice:

- learn how to use debugger to debug and ispect code step by step.
- write nice code. If you can read it easily then you quicker find bugs (e.g code which should go out of `while`)

Comment: Thanks a lot elanius

Comment: @AyushiSingh You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer you can accept it.